# How to remove border of the system tray at top of the screen in flutter android app

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-application

The same code i run in iOS emulator and it  doesn't give any top system tray border but when i run it on any android phone, i get it. I have searched on the internet but i couldn't find any solution to it.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the change in colour at the status bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want change the color of upper layer please try below code.

Import below library

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Add below code inside main method

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light),
  );
}
```

Try below Code as per [SystemUiOverlayStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlayStyle-class.html):

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white, 
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark   
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,    
));
```

Status bar dark:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
```

Status bar light:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
```

Comment: Sir, i am facing another issue, by using the above code, everything is working fine on android but i doesn't work on iOS. in my light theme the system tray icons become white and i can't see anything on iOS

Comment: @SharjeelM. I have update my answer please check hope its help to you